# pyexcel / openpyxl TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'noTextEdit'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to Python, i was try in to access a file via openpyxl and

on using the following code:

```
import openpyxl
wb1=openpyxl.load_workbook('DATA_G1.xlsm')
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'noTextEdit''
```

EDIT1: I'm putting here the complete line

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> os.chdir('C:\\Users\\stephinj\\OneDrive\\LEARN_CODE')
>>> wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('DATA_G1.xlsm')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 276, in load_workbook
for c in find_charts(archive, rel.target):
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 50, in find_charts
drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'noTextEdit''
```

Edit2:

```
>>> print(openpyxl.__version__)
2.5.8
>>> wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 175, in load_workbook
archive = _validate_archive(filename)
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 122, in _validate_archive
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1182, in __init__
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test'
```

Edit3: Solved

Found Error, its because of some bug related to 'Autoshape' object in excel sheet

```
File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 50, in find_charts
drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyexcel / openpyxl \_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312895/pyexcel-openpyxl-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-error)

Comment: as metioned in the LINK I have already upgraded "openpyxl" and "pyexcel" but i still kept getting the same error

Comment: Can you try after saving the file as `.xlsx`? `.xlsm` is macro-enabled excel. Also remove any kind of password protection, if any.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of  `print(openpyxl.__version__)` and `wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('test')`.

Comment: ok, ill do that

Comment: @shiva There are no password protection on the file, i saved it as `.xlsx` file and tried again but recieved same error

Comment: @Stephinn You can add your findings as an answer.

Comment: @shiva How do i do that

Comment: @Stephinn At the bottom of this page, click on `Answer Your question` followed by `Yes, I want to post an answer`

Comment: thanks, i will update that

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Found Error, its because of some bug related to 'Autoshape' object in excel sheet

```
File "C:\Users\stephinj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 50, in find_charts
drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
```